# Public / guest Issue Tracker

Tags: git, gitlab

i'm currently testing with Gitlab CE and i want to use private repos with public issue trackers.

I tried to add a seconde repo for each private repo with public flag. Is there a way to open the issue tracker for guests? Or how can i open the registration for everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening the issue tracker for guests is currently (GitLab 7.2) not possible. However, fou can enable users to sign up themselves by enabling `signup_enabled` in [gitlab.yml](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/config/gitlab.yml.example#L55).

Comment: Ok i did but how to reload the config? Because singup is not shown. (I uses to gitlab.yml @ /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc)

Comment: ok nvm ... restarted with  gitlab-ctl restart :) thanks for your help